# How to find the total volume of a 3D dataset?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a 3D dataset D=260*320*100 of 100 slice. After segmentation I need to Know the total volume (found as total number of pixel) of the 3D dataset. I tried whit this code, but I'm not able to find the total volume of the object in D, it give me error.
Is someone able to help me?

```
CCvol = bwconncomp(D(:,:,:), 8);
STATS = regionprops(CCvol, 'Area');
Volume=sum(STATS.Area)
```

Comment: what about `Volume=sum(vertcat(STATS.Area)))`? That's just a guess haha

Comment: What "error" would this be?  Also, I think you're right @Benoit_11!